# Using Young tableaux with weights for writing down character formula

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I have been learning about [Young tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Tableaux) and I was thinking about the simplest possible use for Young tableaux with weights.

There's a formula for the character of an irreducible representation of $S_n$ corresponding to a Young tableau of shape $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_l)$, evaluated on the conjugacy class given by a $\mu=(\mu_1,\dotsc,\mu_m)$ is given by a coefficient of a multinomial expansion involving $\mu$ and $\lambda$.

The formula is $\chi_\lambda(\mu)=$ coefficient of some monomial in $\prod_{1 \leq i<j \leq l} (x_i-x_j) \prod_{i=1}^m (x_1^{\mu_i}+\dotsb+x_l^{\mu_i})$.

This suggests that one might be able to rewrite this formula using weighted Young diagrams where some of the squares are weighted according to $\mu$.  (Maybe one of the squares is weighted $\mu_i$ times or something).

Do any of you know how to do this/if there's a place where this is done?

Comment: This character is essentially by definition a Schur polynomial, which is well-known to be a generating function for semistandard Young tableaux. I'm confused as to what the question is...

Comment: I made a few edits.  Just as a note:  'Young' is a name, so it's usually capitalised.  'Tableau' is singular and 'tableaux' is plural.  Use $\prod$ `$\prod$` rather than $\Pi$ `$\Pi$` for products (and similarly $\sum$ `$\sum$` rather than $\Sigma$ `$\Sigma$` for sums).  (Compare $\displaystyle\prod_{i = 1}^m i$ `$$\prod_{i = 1}^m i$$` *versus* $\displaystyle\Pi_{i = 1}^m i$ `$\Pi_{i = 1}^m i$`.)

Comment: In your formula for $\chi_\lambda(\mu)$ , you need to take the coefficient of $x_1^{\lambda_1+l-1}x_2^{\lambda_2+l-2}\cdots x_l^{\lambda_l}$. The combinatorial interpretation of $\chi_\lambda(\mu)$ that follows from this is just the Murnaghan-Nakayama rule. This is explained, for instance, in Section 7.17 of my book *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2.

Comment: I think the question should be made more precise. The formula is incorrectly stated and it is $\lambda$ not $\mu$ that refers to the partition (not tableau). Have voted to close.

Comment: The murnaghan narayana rule is essentially what you ask for. A sum over certain tableaux...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Nakayama, not narayana :)

Comment: @user61318 Ah, damn autocorrect! In any case, here is the MN-rule: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~peal/polynomials/schur.htm#schurMurnaghanNakaygama

Comment: Thank you Richard, Per and Sam for the helpful comments.

Comment: And thanks for the patience.  This is not my primary field.  I have been working mostly in homotopy theory for the past 5-6 years or so.